# Delphi reproduce OLE_COLOR

Tags: delphi

Trying to reproduce an OLE_COLOR by translating it to some value I can use in Delphi.  My particular need is to reproduce an Outlook OlCategoryColor.  I can read it as an integer:  yellow gives 4641276, for example, but this doesn't resemble any equivalent of yellow I can find.  I gather that system.drawing has a colorconverter method that should do the trick, but my version of Delphi (10 Seattle) doesn't seem to have system.drawing. It appears that it was available in Delphi 7, and one could add it to  Delphi 8 by adding the .dll to Project References, but Seattle doesn't seem to have Project References.  Thank you as always.

Comment: You are getting pretty mixed up. System.Drawing is a .net namespace. Check if the high byte is $80 and if so call GetSysColor with the index.

Comment: But I believe that the VCL already does this for you. So perhaps you could provide something concrete for us to work with.

Answer (score 2):

The helper function `ColorToRGB` from the `Graphics` unit converts from an OLE color to RGB. It simply tests for the high bit being set, and if so calls `GetSysColor` passing the index encoded in the rest of the value.

However, your color value of `4641276` is not of that form. In hex it is `$0046D1FC`. That is a plain RGB value.

Answer (score 1):

`OLE_COLOR` is a 4-byte RGB color in `$00BBGGRR` format.  This is the same format that `COLORREF` uses, as does Delphi's `VCL.Graphics.TColor` for *non-system* RGB colors (`TColor` uses `$800000xx` format for *system* colors, where `xx` is an index defined by the Win32 `GetSysColor()` function).

So, you can freely cast RGB values directly between `OLE_COLOR`, `COLORREF` and `TColor`.  When assigning a `TColor` to a `COLORREF` or `OLE_COLOR`, you should use the VCL's `ColorToRGB()` function to make sure the `TColor` is converted to an actual RGB value first, in case it holds a system color.

That being said, the numeric value `4641276` is hex `$0046D1FC`, which is `R=252 G=209 B=70`, which is a goldish yellow:

[image: yellow color]

---

**UPDATE**: apparently `OLE_COLOR` also supports the same `$800000xx` format that `Vcl.Graphics.TColor` does for system-defined colors.  In that case, when assigning an `OLE_COLOR` to a `COLORREF`, use [`OleTranslateColor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694353.aspx) instead.  You can freely assign values as-is between `OLE_COLOR` and `TColor` since they use the same formats for both system and non-system colors.

Comment: First part isn't right. The fourth "channel" can be $80 to indicate index of sys color.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That only applies to `Vcl.Graphics.TColor`, not to `OLE_COLOR` or `COLORREF` at all.  That is why I said "*`TColor` **non-system** RGB colors*".

Comment: Many references state otherwise. For instance http://gfabasic32.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/what-to-do-with-olecolor.html?m=1 or from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694353(v=vs.85).aspx